# How is it justified to take the tensor product of nonlinear functions?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, tensor-products, tensors

Suppose $f, g: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$. If $f$ and $g$ are both linear then we may define the tensor $$(f \otimes g)(x_1,\ldots,x_{2n}) = f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)g(x_{n+1}, \ldots,x_{2n})$$ by taking the tensor product as above.

This definition only applies to linear functions. However I often see this applied to nonlinear functions as well, for example in PDE. How is this justified?

Comment: Since $f$ and $g$ have values in $\mathbb{R}^n$, how is the multiplication of the two values in the expression $f(x_1, \dots, x_n) g(x_{n+1},\dots,  x_{2n})$ to be understood?

Comment: This $f\otimes g$ is not a tensor as we know it from DG. It is a (not necessarily linear) function on $\mathbb R^n\times\mathbb R^n\,.$ Forgive them that they use $\otimes\,.$ Measure & probability theoretics  use it also to denote a product measure which is probably closer in spirit to that non linear function example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to consider the case where both functions have values in a field instead of a vector space, since i am not sure how the multiplication on the right hand side of the first equation in the question is to be interpreted otherwise.

The identification of $f\otimes g$ with a two variable function is a consequence of the below proposition 1.

**Notation**: Let $S,T$ be sets and $\mathbb{K} \in \{ \mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}\}$ fixed. Let $V$ be a $\mathbb{K}$ vector space. Denote by $F(S,V)$ the vector space of all functions $f: S \to V$ (with $F(S) = F(S, \mathbb{K})$).

> **Proposition 1:** The map
> \begin{align*}
> H: F(S) \otimes F(T) &\longrightarrow F(S \times T) \\
> \sum_{i=1}^n f_i \otimes g_i & \longmapsto \bigg( (s,t) \mapsto \sum_{i=1}^n f_i(s) g_i(t) \bigg)
> \end{align*}
> is linear and injective.

This proposition allows us to identify $F(S) \otimes F(T)$ with a subspace ($= \operatorname{ran} H$) of $F(S\times T)$, which is exactly what is being done in the question.

Proposition 1 follows from a more general proposition:

> **Proposition 2:** The map
> $$
> \begin{align*}
> J: F(S) \otimes V &\longrightarrow F(S,V) \\
> \sum_{i=1}^n f_i \otimes v_i & \longmapsto \bigg( s \mapsto \sum_{i=1}^n f_i(s) v_i \bigg)
> \end{align*}
> $$
> is linear and injective.

**Proof of Proposition 2:**
$J$ is the linearization of the bilinear map $F(S) \times V \to F(S, V), \ (f,v) \mapsto (s \mapsto f(s) v)$. Therefore $J$ is well defined and linear.

It is left to show injectivity:
Let $ u = \sum_{i=1}^n f_i \otimes v_i \in F(S) \otimes V $ with $J(u) = 0$.

Let $s \in S$ and $\delta_s$ be the "evaluation at $s$ functional" and $\varphi \in V^\prime$ (dual space) be arbitrary.
Then
$$ (\delta_s \otimes \varphi) (u) =  \sum_{i=1}^n f_i(s) \varphi(v_i) = \varphi \bigg(  \sum_{i=1}^n f_i(s) v_i \bigg)=  \varphi ( J(u)(s))= 0
$$
Since $s \in S$ was arbitrary it follows that
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n f_i \varphi(v_i) =0$$
for all $ \varphi \in V^\prime$, but this implies that $u=0$ (a well known criterion, for example in "Introduction to
Tensor Products of
Banach Spaces" by Ryan, proposition 1.2) and therefore $J$ is injective.

**Proof of Proposition 1:**
Choose $V= F(T)$ and let $ K : F(S, F(T)) \to F(S \times T)$ be the isomorphism defined by $K(f) = ( (s,t) \mapsto f(s)(t))$. Then $H = K \circ J$ and so proposition 1 follows.

Comment: Thank you! For vector valued functions I think the identity is to be applied component wise as in $(f \otimes g)_{ij} = f_ig_j$.

Comment: @CBBAM Ah okay. That case also follows from my answer using that $J$ is an isomorphism when $V$ is finite dimensional.